# Searching the head of CVS

Tags: cvs

I'm looking for a 'relatively' easy way to search through cvs to look for a particular string in the HEAD revisions.

I realize the way CVS stores versions makes this difficult. But I'm trying to come up with some script to allow this search (performance is not expected here).

Currently this command will output the contents of the head files
cvs co -r HEAD -p

stdout = file contents (to be grepped for the search string)
stderr = the file name/header info (to be grepped for the line that signifies file name).

Ideally, I want to grep the contents and display the header + a few lines before and after the searched item (the output of this likely directed to some file).

I found a way to grep the stdout and stderr using different values. And the resulting stdout/stderr displayed is in the right order. But any attempt to redirect it to a file messes up the order?

```
{
  { cvs co -r HEAD -p myModule 4>&- | grep 'myString' 2>&4 4>&-
  } 4>&2 2>&1 >&3 3>&- | grep 'Check' >&2 3>&-
} 3>&1
```

Question 1. Is there an easier way to do this all together?

Question 2. If not, how do I get the output of the code above to append to a file in the same order as displayed on the console?

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple of suggestions:

- You can use the "script" command to log your session in the right order. (See: 'man script')
- For grep, if you want to insert context, you can use the -A, -B, -C options. (See: 'man grep', look for 'Context Line Control'.

Good luck.